# why does Timestamp print difference between run model and debug model in unit test?

Tags: java, timestamp, sqldatetime

```
    java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("1900-01-01");
    //-2209017600000
    System.out.println(date.getTime());
    java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

if directly running in unit test, the result will be `1900-01-01 00:00:00.0`

if running with debug in unit test, the result will be `1970-01-01 07:30:00.0`

How does it output `1900-01-01 00:00:00.0`? Where is it stored?

Why not output `1970-01-01 00:00:00.0` ? becase I saw the comment of Timestamp constructor says milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT. A negative number is the number of milliseconds before January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

Comment: If you're using `java.time.LocalDateTime`, then your code won't compile - you might want to highlight any other libraries or custom classes you are using

Comment: I tried but I get in unit test and debug unit test. Outputs are matching. I get `1900-01-01 00:00:00.0` . Which version 1.8 or 1.7 or else?

Comment: @drowny i used  jdk version 1.8 ,  my local timezone is Singapore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Avoid the terrible old date-time classes. Use *java.time*. Poof, all the bizarre behavior you are seeing is gone, and your question is moot.

```
LocalDate                 // A class to represent a date-only value, without time-of-day, without time zone. Replaces `java.sql.Date` which only pretends to be date-only but actually has both a time-of-day and a time zone.
.parse( "1900-01-01" )    // Standard ISO 8601 formatted strings are parsed directly by the *java.time* classes. 
.atStartOfDay(            // Let java.time determine the first moment of a day.
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) 
)                         // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toString()               // Generates a `String` with text in standard ISO 8601 format, wisely extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 1900-01-01T00:00+11:30[Pacific/Auckland]

You are torturing yourself with these Questions about the legacy date-time classes. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on those classes years ago when adopting [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). I suggest you do the same.

## Never use `java.sql.Date`

This class is part of the terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by *java.time* classes. This `java.sql.Date` in particular is especially badly designed. It extends `java.util.Date` while the documentation tells us to ignore the fact of that inheritance. As a subclass, it *pretends* to be a date-only value but actually has a time-of-day inherited from the other `Date`, which in turn is misnamed having both a date and a time-of-day. In addition, a time zone lurks deep within these classes, though inaccessible without any getter or setter method. Confusing? Yes, an awful mess. Never use `java.sql.Date`.

Instead, use `java.time.LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "1900-01-01" ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 1900-01-01

## Never use `java.sql.Timestamp`

As with `java.sql.Date`, the `java.sql.Timestamp` class was replaced years ago. Use `java.time.Instant`. If handed a `Timestamp`, immediately convert using the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

If you want the first moment of the day for a particular date, let `LocalDate` determine that. The first moment is *not* always 00:00:00, so never assume that. Specify the time zone of the region whose people use the particular wall-clock time you care about.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

To see the same moment in UTC, extract a `Instant`. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

If you wanted the first moment of the day in UTC, use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ld.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## Conversion

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time* classes, you can convert back-and-forth. Call new methods added to the old classes.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from( instant ) ;
```

…and…

```
Instant instant = ts.toInstant() ;
```

Ditto for date.

```
java.sql.Date d = java.sql.Date.valueOf( ld ) ;
```

…and…

```
LocalDate ld = d.toLocalDate() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).